# PHP fopen slow in local Vagrant Homestead instance

Tags: php, performance, vagrant, fopen, homestead

I'm trying to load an image from an external site (like https://loremflickr.com/400/300/ ) to store on my own server.

When I run the script on a normal (external) server everything works fine and the image is loaded pretty quickly, but when I run the exact same thing on a local Vagrant Homestead instance it becomes super slow and 9 out of 10 times it resulting in a `fopen(): SSL: Connection reset by peer` error.

When I try to load an image from a site that doesn't give a timeout the image is eventually (so the code itself isn't the issue) loaded but most of the time it takes over a full minute to do so.

The reset of the Vagrant instance seems to run just fine without any noticeable lag.

I use `fopen()` but also tried with curl but with the same result.

Any clue on what might cause this?

Comment: What network type is used for vagrant box?

Comment: are you using nfs?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! I started messing a bit with the `config.vm.network` setting and after reprovisioning the server it ran like a charm. Oddly enough, putting the settings back to what it was (:public_network) and reprovisioning it still runs smooth. Very strange; probably a glitch in the matrix :)